# "Invalid Column id" error when counting unique value in Java

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I am using the following `sql` query in my java program:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE externaleventid ='1256294';
```

But I have an error as:

> **Invalid Column id.**

Same query works fine in `SQL Developer`.

Comment: Please post your Java code that executes this query and attempts to process the result set.

Comment: String query = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE externaleventid =?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
pstmt.setString(1,"1256294"); 
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();       
while (rs.next()) {  
String externaleventid = rs.getString("externaleventid");    System.out.println("externaleventid : " + externaleventid);}
} catch(SQLException se){
se.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
try{
if(stmt!=null)conn.close();
}catch(SQLException se){
}
}try {
if(conn!=null)
conn.close();}catch(SQLException se){se.printStackTrace();}

Comment: I am using the above code after making jdbc connection as follows:public static void main(String) {
Connection conn= null;try{
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   System.out.println("connecting to a database");
   //Making JDBC connection
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
   System.out.println("Database connection successfully");
   System.out.println("creating statement");

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are attempting to get a column named "externaleventid" from the query, but only "count(*)" is available.  You shouldn't try to get back the where clause bind variables from the result set, you should get the actual data back from the result set, by column index or by column name.

Try `rs.getInt(1)` to get the data from the first column.  Or, you can alias the column in the query, e.g. `SELECT count(*) cnt FROM...`, and you can refer to it by the aliased column name: `rs.getInt("cnt")`.